strftime() alternating formats for the same placeholder
Is it possible in pandas to input alternating strftime() formats for the same placeholder in my word document?
So, let’s say the first row is "(%y %m %d)"; the second row is "(%d %m %y)"; the third row is the same as the first, the fourth is the same as the second, and so on.

Please provide a [MRE] and describe your problem in more detail to avoid misunderstandings.

Use pandas and datetime with a format map.
Example:
data = {
    "date": [datetime(2024, 1, 1), datetime(2024, 2, 2), datetime(2024, 3, 3), datetime(2024, 4, 4)]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Formats you want to alternate between:
formats = ["(%y %m %d)", "(%d %m %y)"]

Apply alternating formats
df['formatted_date'] = df.index.map(lambda idx: df.loc[idx, 'date'].strftime(formats[idx % len(formats)]))

Output:
# Example output compatible with Word documents or LaTeX
output = df['formatted_date'].to_list()

        date formatted_date
0 2024-01-01     (24 01 01)
1 2024-02-02     (02 02 24)
2 2024-03-03     (24 03 03)
3 2024-04-04     (04 04 24)


You could use a custom groupby.apply:
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start='2024-01-01', periods=10, freq='D')})

formats = ['(%y %m %d)', '(%d %m %y)']
df['strftime'] = (df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))%len(formats), group_keys=False)['date']
                    .apply(lambda x: x.dt.strftime(formats[x.name]))
                 )

Variant with groupby.transform and an iterator:
formats = ['(%y %m %d)', '(%d %m %y)']
it = iter(formats)

df['strftime'] = (df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))%len(formats), group_keys=False)['date']
                    .transform(lambda x: x.dt.strftime(next(it)))
                 )

Example:
        date    strftime
0 2024-01-01  (24 01 01)
1 2024-01-02  (02 01 24)
2 2024-01-03  (24 01 03)
3 2024-01-04  (04 01 24)
4 2024-01-05  (24 01 05)
5 2024-01-06  (06 01 24)
6 2024-01-07  (24 01 07)
7 2024-01-08  (08 01 24)
8 2024-01-09  (24 01 09)
9 2024-01-10  (10 01 24)


Option 1: df.loc
Assign values for the even rows ([::2]) and the odd rows ([1::2]) separately.
import pandas as pd

data = {'date': pd.date_range('2020-01-01', periods=10_000)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

format_even ='(%y %m %d)'
format_odd = '(%d %m %y)'
 
df.loc[df.index[::2], 'formatted_date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime(format_even)
df.loc[df.index[1::2], 'formatted_date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime(format_odd)

Output:
# df.head()

        date formatted_date
0 2020-01-01     (20 01 01)
1 2020-01-02     (02 01 20)
2 2020-01-03     (20 01 03)
3 2020-01-04     (04 01 20)
4 2020-01-05     (20 01 05)

Option 2: np.where
Create a boolean series with True for each even row.
import numpy as np

df['formatted_date'] = np.where(np.arange(len(df)) % 2 == 0, 
                                df['date'].dt.strftime(format_even), 
                                df['date'].dt.strftime(format_odd)
                                )

Performance comparision
map_lambda refers to the method suggested by @EuanG. Both option 1 and 2 perform better.
%timeit loc(df.copy())
%timeit npwhere(df.copy())
%timeit map_lambda(df.copy())

Results:
148 ms ± 24.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
133 ms ± 19.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
237 ms ± 5.77 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Equality check:
dfs = [loc(df.copy()),
       npwhere(df.copy()),
       map_lambda(df.copy())]
all(df.equals(dfs[0]) for df in dfs)
# True

